# Java AES/CBC/NoPadding equivalent in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, node-crypto

I have been assigned to decode tokens built in java using **AES/CBC/NoPadding**.

I am looking into node-forge and crypto for this. My problem is that I don't know what is the equivalent for the algorithm **AES/CBC/NoPadding** in NodeJs.

I'm using something like this:

```
var key = Array(xxx); // key.length = 16
var iv = new Buffer(16);
iv.fill(0);

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, iv);
```

As I searched, this `createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb"` is equivalent to **AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding**. I though of `decipher.setPadding(false)` but I guess I'm in the wrong path).

Comment: You need padding with a block based cipher unless every message is an exact multiple of the block size, 16-bytes for AES. The typical padding is PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5).

Comment: Provide a [mcve] including sample data.

Comment: There is a "Favorite" also.

Comment: This is not a code request.... please, don't understand my question as such...

I've been requested the decryption in Node Js, based on a working java. That is already done, with the exception that I don't find anywhere, which algorithym to use...

Right now, I have something like:

crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, iv); 

where key is an Array(16) and iv is a Buffer(16).

When I run my code, it breaks on this line, with "Invalid IV length".

From what i've searched, aes-128-ecb matches AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java (and that is not what I need).

Comment: ECB mode does not use an IV. `aes-128-ecb` is **not** equivalent to `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`. ECB and CBC are encryption modes, PKCS5Padding is adding padding bytes to the end of the data during  encrypted so it wi be a multiple of the block size and removing the padding on decryption. Take some time and study AES encryption, modes and padding.

Comment: "Convert this custom crypto from one language to another" is notoriously difficult to have answered on SO. I don't answer them any more because they're too specific to one code base and aren't reusable by future searchers. If you do need this kind of work done, I recommend contracting someone for a short engagement. Lots of people handle this kind of work, including me, and it generally isn't very expensive if the algorithm is simple and you have a working version and test cases.

Comment: Managed to resolve the issue and have a working solution now... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Using `forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC', key);` did the job...

Internally it uses padding, but I could overcome the issue adding some garbage before decryption and then taking care of the remaining garbage after internal padding.

Comment: Deciphering requires unpadding, not padding. And usually if unpadding fails an error is thrown. Could you possibly share the code?